# jquery event handler to execute only once the is bound to multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I want to have an event handler that executes only once and then unbinds itself from all the elements it was bound to.

I know of `.one()` but when using it "The handler is executed at most once **per element**".

Is there a "built-in" way to bind an event handler to multiple elements and have it removed automatically from all of the once it is executed on any one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Just unbind the event handler inside the callback function. Like this:

```
$('p').on('click', function(){
  alert('I appear only one time');
  $('p').off('click'); // Removes the event. So, it will never be executed again.
})
```

This script will remove all events of type *click*, and that is a bit aggresive. Check the documentation for [**off**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [**unbind**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) for more info.

Comment: working like this is bound to result in some trouble at some point.
If I will have to do this manually I would write my one .once(handler) that will keep both the pointer to "this" and handler and will bind an alternative handler that in turn will remove only the handlers it added. It's just that I was hoping that JQuery already has something like this...

Comment: In that case, I don't know of any existing jquery function that works like that.
That approach doesn't seem very error prone to me, but implementing an jquery _fn.once()_ function that attachs a second event that automatically removes other events may be complicated. You have to take care of events precedence, events with _stopPropagation_ may not be unbinded.... it seems even more complicated that just add one line on your callback function.

Comment: accepted for the " I don't know of any existing jquery function that works like that"...

Answer (score 1):

miguel camba already told you to check the wiki for unbind. The correct solution would be the following:

```
    var handler = function() {
        alert('I appear only one time');
         $('p').unbind('click', handler);
    }
    $('p').bind('click', handler);
```

This will unbind only this handler from the click event.

//Edit:

Another solution would be to namespace your click event:

```
$('p').bind('click.myClickEvent', function() {
    alert('I appear only one time');
    $('p').unbind('click.myClickEvent');
});
```

Comment: I like the first approach of using a closure. as for the second solution it still does not feel "re-entrant" enough for my taste in the sense that if I put this in a function that gets the alert as a parameter then calling it multiple times would make only a single alert begin fired instead of one alert per call to the function.

Comment: can the first solution be achieved using .on() and .off() ?

Comment: i guess it's pretty much the same