# Jquery stop the first clicked button from executing the same code

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue seems like it would be on here already but I just can't find it. Apologies in advance!!!!

After clicking one of multiple (unique) buttons, the initial corresponding div selected keeps executing even when clicking a different button.

How can I stop the first clicked button from executing the same code?

HTML

```
<button id="freeButton" type="button">Redeem</button>
<button id="giftCardButton" type="button">Redeem</button>
```

Jquery

```
content[0] = content;
content[1] = other content;

$(freeButton).click(function(){
    if(!visible) {
        $('#items').append(content[0]);
            visible = true;
    } else {
        $('#items').remove(content[0]);
            visible = false;
    }
});

$(giftCardButton).click(function(){
    if(!visible) {
        $('#items').append(content[1]);
            visible = true;
    } else {
        $('#items').remove(content[1]);
            visible = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#freeButton')` rather than `$(freeButton)`? Or do you have variables with declarations not shown?

Comment: @nnnnnn it is valid window.freeButton variable, 'unfortunately' standardised in HTML5

Comment: @A.Wolff - Supported in all browsers? Even so, I think it is bad practice to do it only some of the time (noting that the code above has `$('#items')`.

Comment: @nnnnnn declarations are not shown, its quite a bit of HTML

Comment: @nnnnnn in all HTML5 compilant browserz, ID or NAME of html element becoming global variable

Comment: What is the scope of `visible`?

Comment: Create a single selection of all elements, bind a "single" event handler, unbind the handler when it's called. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11280817/218196.

Comment: Do you mean if you click on button 1, it will set visible to true and when you click on button 2 it shouldn't be visible and thus not append content to the div? You may need different visible variables for each event. What you ask is not very clear.

Comment: @gyc when I click button 1 it shows content 1. Without reloading the page, when I click on button 2 it shows content 1.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dojw6ovg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line $('#items').remove(content[1]); you are removing the element from the dom and with append you are not replacing the content of the div, you're just adding to it.

you need to use the html() methode instead.

```js
var content = ["content", "other content"];
visible = false;

$('#freeButton').click(function(){
    if(!visible) {
        $('#items').html(content[0]);
            visible = true;
    } else {
        $('#items').html("");
            visible = false;
    }
});
$('#giftCardButton').click(function(){
    if(!visible) {
        $('#items').html(content[1]);
            visible = true;
    } else {
        $('#items').html("");
            visible = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="freeButton" type="button">Redeem1</button>
<button id="giftCardButton" type="button">Redeem2</button>
<div id="items"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way to clear the content once another button is clicked?

Comment: @ekm383 to empty the div content you can put $('#items').html(""); in a another button.click() event